# Cannot hide a selector, jQuery Uniform plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm using [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) on select controls. I want to hide some of them so I do:

```
$('.selector').hide();
$.uniform.update('.selector');
```

The `$.uniform.update('.selector')` is to sync the changes to uniform. But it's not working, the control just stays visible and no selectable.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it wrapping the selector into a `<div>` and hidding the `<div>`, but I would like to know if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: how does your markup look like (before you wrapped it with a div)?

Comment: <select id="months"></select>

Comment: i can't believe that this is the only solution.  has anyone else dealt with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.uniform.update('selector');
```

is wrong, currently you are trying to find an element named selector, you want to look for the ID instead:

```
$.uniform.update('#selector');
```

if you got an element that has and ID of selector that is.

do you need to show the select box before? I tired

```
$('select').hide().uniform();
```

and to show it:

```
$('select').show().parent().show();
```

It may not be what you are looking for tho.

Answer (score 1):

I have defined a function:

```
$.uniform.updateSelectors = function() {
    $.uniform.update();
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).parent(".selector").toggle($(this).css("display") != "none");
    });
};
```

Not pretty, but nicer than directly manipulating uniform divs, be

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to target the tag element "<select>" and then the parent ".selector":

```
$('select').parent('.selector').hide();
```